# What does term in function mean?

Tags: r, function, arguments

Hi sorry still learning here and slow to learning code arguments.

Just wondering could anyone explain what a certain part of a function means:

```
x = sum(abs(apply(embed(y, 4), 1, prod)))
```

It does give the following on paper:

```
#sum(y|{j}|*y|{j-1}|*y|{j-2}|*|y{j-3}|)
```

I am wondering what does the `1` do? as I think the `(y, 4)` means y with y plus 3 lags and `prod` I know is product

this specific function was wrote for be by I am trying to modify it to equal:

```
#sum((|y{j}|^3/2)*(|y{j-1}|^3/2)*(|y{j-2}|^3/2)*(|y{j-3}|^3/2))
```

So basically I am wondering should my modified function to raise the y's to ^3/2 should I compute:

```
x = sum(abs(apply(embed((y^3/2), 4), 1, prod)))
```

or to:

```
x = sum(abs(apply(embed(y, 4), 3/2, prod)))
```

or another?

Any help?

Thank you in advance for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1` is part of the `apply` function of argument called `MARGIN`. This is why I advocate specifying argument names. Anyway, `apply` function will "loop" through rows (1) or columns (2) of data frames, arrays, matrices... An expression or an evaluated object should be passed as `X` or if you prefer your functions bare, the first argument. If you want to raise `y` by some amount, you will have to do it like you've showed in one of the lines: `y^(3/2)`.

In other words, this command will sum all elements across rows:

```
apply(X = my.object, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum)
```

or across columns:

```
apply(X = my.object, MARGIN = 2, FUN = sum)
```